# Passing btimap image from one activity to another activity without loosing quality of image

Tags: android

When i pass captured image result from one activity to another activity image is loosing quality and getting blur.
Is there any way to pass big size image from one activity to another activity without loosing quality???

Comment: are you passing bitmap ??

Comment: Do not pass bitmap in bundle . Instead of it you can use a Singleton Utility class to set the bitmap .

Comment: @ADM, I'd not suggest doing that.

Comment: @VladMatvienko So what you suggest then let me know .Passing local Url can be a solution . What you think will be best.

Comment: I'd save Bitmap to file, and passed URI to it to the next activity through bundle

Comment: Yeah thats what i think . the Singleton approach can also work in case of a bitmap . but we need to take care of recycling it once the work done .Thx

Comment: yes i am passing a bitmap @SahdevRajput74

Answer (score 0):

Avoid passing large objects via Bundle, use `LruCache<Bitmap>` to cache the Bitmap in memory for quick retrieval on the other end. See this link

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html